# intuitive explanation/derivation of likelihood function for logistic regression

Tags: intuition, maximum-likelihood, logistic-regression

I'm struggling to wrap my head around the intuitiveness of the likelihood function for logistic regression shown below. If you could please explain why: A) you want to have a joint probability function
B) you want to take 1-P(X) for all non-cases for this
joint probability function.

[image]